# Path.GetExtension returning ""

Tags: c#, file-upload, upload

I am trying to upload an image path into database and save file in the images folder. This works correctly except for the getExtension part (.jpg, .gif etc...) the Path.GetExtension method is always returning null ("") and I don't have any idea why.

Below you can find the code used:

```
string imagesFolderPath = Server.MapPath("//Images");
imagesFolderPath += "//";

string newImageName = addProduct.id.ToString();
string extension = Path.GetExtension(fileUpload.FileName.ToString());

addProduct.imagePath = "Images//" + newImageName + extension;

fileUpload.SaveAs(imagesFolderPath + newImageName);
```

Comment: It would help if we knew what `fileUpload.FileName.ToString()` returned.

Comment: Can you confirm if the `FileName` has an extension

Comment: As Filename is a _string_, why are you calling ToString on it : _fileUpload.FileName.ToString()_ ?

Comment: Please see my answer below, did you get it worked out with that clarification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getextension.aspx):

> The extension of the specified path (including the period "."), or null, or String.Empty. If path is null, GetExtension returns null. ***If path does not have extension information, GetExtension returns String.Empty.***

The only way you can get an empty string, `""`, is for the path to ***not*** be `null` *and* the path to ***not*** have an extension.

You're getting an empty string because the path doesn't have an extension.

Comment: I'm getting "" for C:\Windows\system32\dllhost.exe /Processid:{02D4B3F1-FD88-11D1-960D-00805FC79235} path using GetExtension method.

Comment: @SamFlushing that's because `C:\Windows\system32\dllhost.exe /Processid:{02D4B3F1-FD88-11D1-960D-00805FC79235}` isn't a valid path.

Comment: Thanks. I guess they should implement functions to support executable argument as well.